# Why my custom Layout Inflater Factory onCreateView never gets excecuted?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have created this custom Layout Inflater Factory Class and have set it to a clone of the Layout Inflater as recommended in the documentation. The APP runs but the onCreateView is never called on my custom class.

Researching LayoutInflater.java I can see that It should be called from createViewFromTag, but it is getting difficult to trace in which situation this method is executed.

The menu I am trying to customize is the Action Overflow Menu.

Any idea what could be wrong?

My custom Inflater Factory Class:

```
public class MyLayoutInflaterFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory {
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                             AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(
                "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
            try {
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.banner_kid_yellow_blue);
                        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(20);

                        Typeface face = MyApplication.getDefaultTypeface();
                        ((TextView) view).setTypeface(face);
                        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                });
                return view;
            } catch (InflateException e) {
                //Handle any inflation exception here
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                //Handle any ClassNotFoundException here
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My OnCreateMenuOptions method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);

    LayoutInflater inflaterClone = getLayoutInflater().cloneInContext(getLayoutInflater().getContext());
    LayoutInflater.Factory lif = new MyLayoutInflaterFactory();
    inflaterClone.setFactory(lif);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

onCreateView will be called only when the layout is inflated using inflator object which has factory set to it.

View should be inflated **before** **setContentView** of actvity.

in your case you can inflate the menu layout before setContentView and store custom tag data for future use.

write code in your on create before setContentView()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
if (inflater.getFactory() != null) {
   inflater = inflater.cloneInContext(this);
}
inflater.setFactory(<your factory class object>);
View v = inflater.inflate(<your layout>, null);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call the factory onCreateView manually from within your activity onCreateView. because activity's onCreateView returns null by default so if you want other wise you can do like this

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if(name.contains("ActionMenuItemView")) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = null;
            try {
                view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (view != null) {
                if(factory != null) {
                    view = mFactory.onCreateView(name,context,attrs);
                }
                return view;
            }
        }
        return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }
```

which will check if LayoutInflater can create the view then trigger the factory onCreateView to edit it

Answer (score -4):

Please add @Override before declaring public class onCreateView.